# Swift protocol extension with specific Self type

Tags: swift, protocols, protocol-extension

I added an extension for the UnsignedInteger protocol to add a hex method that represents the number in hex format. I also want for specific conforming structs to have default value for a parameter. What I wrote is the below.

```
extension UnsignedInteger {
    func hex(withFieldWidth fieldWidth: Int, andUseUppercase uppercase: Bool = true) -> String {
        return String(format: "%0\(fieldWidth)\(uppercase ? "X" : "x")", self as! CVarArg)
    }
}

extension UnsignedInteger where Self == UInt8 {
    func hex(withFieldWidth fieldWidth: Int = 2, andUseUppercase uppercase: Bool = true) -> String {
        // should call the UnsignedInteger implementation with the default parameters
        return hex(withFieldWidth: fieldWidth, andUseUppercase: uppercase)
    }
}

extension UnsignedInteger where Self == UInt16 {
    func hex(withFieldWidth fieldWidth: Int = 4, andUseUppercase uppercase: Bool = true) -> String {
        // should call the UnsignedInteger implementation with the default parameters
        return hex(withFieldWidth: fieldWidth, andUseUppercase: uppercase)
    }
}
```

However, for the UInt8 and UInt16 specific extensions, it seems to be calling itself and not the hex from the first extension block, as explained by the warning message I get for the UInt8 and UInt16 blocks: `All paths through this function will call itself`.

If I remove the `fieldWidh` from the UInt8 and UInt16 blocks, calling hex (with hardcoded values for `fieldWidth`) seems to compile fine, I believe this way it is calling the hex method from the first extension block. Below is the code that compiles fine.

```
extension UnsignedInteger {
    func hex(withFieldWidth fieldWidth: Int, andUseUppercase uppercase: Bool = true) -> String {
        return String(format: "%0\(fieldWidth)\(uppercase ? "X" : "x")", self as! CVarArg)
    }
}

extension UnsignedInteger where Self == UInt8 {
    func hex(andUseUppercase uppercase: Bool = true) -> String {
        // should call the UnsignedInteger implementation with the default parameters
        return hex(withFieldWidth: 2, andUseUppercase: uppercase)
    }
}

extension UnsignedInteger where Self == UInt16 {
    func hex(andUseUppercase uppercase: Bool = true) -> String {
        // should call the UnsignedInteger implementation with the default parameters
        return hex(withFieldWidth: 4, andUseUppercase: uppercase)
    }
}
```

Is there a way to specify a default value for the parameter for specific conforming structs when doing a protocol extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is there a way to specify a default value for the parameter for specific conforming structs when doing a protocol extension?**

> You have highlighted the problems with this approach in the question already.

---

**How can I solve it in a different way?**

> [`UnsignedInteger`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsignedinteger) inherits from [`BinaryInteger`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/binaryinteger) that can provide you [`bitWidth`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/binaryinteger/2886690-bitwidth) information (`UInt8` => `8`, `UInt16` => `16` and so on).

```
extension UnsignedInteger {
    func hex(uppercase: Bool = true) -> String {
        let fieldWidth = self.bitWidth / 4
        return String(format: "%0\(fieldWidth)\(uppercase ? "X" : "x")", self as! CVarArg)
    }
}
```

Above makes it work for `UInt`, `UInt8`, `UInt16`, `UInt32` & `UInt64`.

---

Taking it one step further, you can do this with [`FixedWidthInteger`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/fixedwidthinteger) & now it will work for all signed and unsigned integers.
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Tarun Tyagi, as you mentioned, I used bitWidth to have a default value for the parameter and it worked. But what if there was no bitWidth field, would what I was trying be in any way possible?

Comment: @hakunamatata Swift compiler will rightfully choose a more-specialized implementation (`UInt8`, `UInt16` in your case) of a function rather than choosing a base implementation (`UnsignedInteger` in your case). So when you are calling the `hex(...` with exact same signature as the base implementation, it will always choose the current implementation rather than base implementation. That'll become an infinite loop in itself at runtime - so compiler warns you upfront about this issue.

Comment: @hakunamatata The only solution would be to change function signature in a meaningful way (not just add default value) like you did in 2nd version - which you don't want to do. You want to have same function signature.

Answer (score 1):

This has already been answered but it can be improved. There is no need to force cast as CVarArg you can simply add a constraining where Self: CVarArg. You can also pass the number of characters as a CVarArg of the String initializer and use `*` in your string format.

---

```
extension UnsignedInteger where Self: CVarArg {
    func hex(uppercase: Bool = true) -> String {
        .init(format: "%0*\(uppercase ? "X" : "x")", bitWidth / 4, self)
    }
}
```

---

```
UInt8(255).hex()   // "FF"
UInt8(255).hex(uppercase: false)   // "ff"
UInt16(255).hex()  // "00FF"
UInt16(255).hex(uppercase: false)  // "00ff"
UInt32(255).hex()  // "000000FF"
UInt32(255).hex(uppercase: false)  // "000000ff"
```

Comment: Yeah I didn't notice that the UInt types conform to it, this will let me avoid casting self. Thanks @Leo Dabus.